# Replacing fragments in FragmentActivity is freezing my application for more than 5 seconds

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentmanager

I have `FragmentActivity` called `StartupActivity`. This activity holds 5 `Fragments` -> `LoginFragment, LostPasswordFragment, RegistrationFragment, Login2Fragment, CityPickFragment`. I can switch between fragments using `ToolBar` **BackButton**. Problem is, that replacing certain fragment using suppportFragmentManager and simple transaction is lagging the app. If I click **BackButton** it takes nearly **5 second** to switch fragment. `Fragments` has simple layout with **1 ImageView 2 EditTexts and Button (+ ToolBar)**.

Do you know what can be wrong?

Here is code example how fragment switching works. As I start `StartupActivity` right after `SplashScreen`, it will create all 5 Fragments as variables and it will set default `Fragment` to **FrameLayout container**.

Then in each 5 fragments is back button in toolbar and I set `onClickListener()` which calls method in `parentActivity` to **switch fragment**.

My Fragments have **Tags**, because I have to disable **onBackPressed()** at first fragment(You cant go back to SplashScreen from default Fragment).

```
//RegistrationFragment
fragmentBackButton.setOnClickListener {
            (activity as StartupActivity).switchToDefaultLoginFragment()
        }

//StartupActivity
fun switchToDefaultLoginFragment(){
        fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.apply {
            replace(R.id.startup_fragment_container, defaultLoginFragment, "LOGIN_FRAGMENT")
            addToBackStack(null)
            commit()
        }
    }
```

Comment: are you doing any heavy time consuming task in your default fragment's oncreate / oncreateView/ onviewcreated / onresume?

Comment: No. Its like login screen. The only stuff what is inside fragment is credentialsValidation (calling asynctask to server from REST API.)

Comment: Have you add some background image to your app ? If yes what is the size of it,  try to remove it and check if lag disapear

Comment: I would create Mock fragment just with TextView  and try to reproduce problem with it and than gradually make this mock looks more and more like original LoginFragment, until you find a problem. Fragment which opens up for 5 sec is not a usual thing, and it safe to assume you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to exucute your code inside Runnable . Like this

```
Handler  mHandler = new Handler();

     Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // update the main content by replacing fragments
                    Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                            android.R.anim.fade_out);
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
                    fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                }
            };

            // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
            if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
                mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
            }
```

Changing Your Fragment on Main Thread causing that issuie

**EDIT: In kotlin you can use like this**

```
private var   mDelayHandler : Handler? = Handler()
 mDelayHandler!!.post(mRunnable)


internal val mRunnable: Runnable = Runnable {
        Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                                android.R.anim.fade_out);
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
                        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    }
                };
    }
```

Comment: Where do you get `mHandler`?

Comment: Same question :)

Comment: Because If I create new handler object it says that mPendingRunnable is not Runnable but Unit (in kotlin method  mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable))

Comment: @martin1337 i've updated my answer . its just `Handler` object

Comment: and how to execute that runnable? Because If I run this code in function it will not run mHandler.post(). I have to add Runnable into Thread and use .start()